# ResultSetManager clobbered after postLoad event handler

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a postLoad event listener that executes a query to retrieve some file data that is popped into an array on the entity that is being loaded. I am doing this because we have a number of different items that need to be added to the entity, but aren't essential to the entity. Right now it is files, but we will eventually have at least 7 of these "items". Instead of creating 7 different mappings to the individual "items", we decided to implement them as services in Symfony that drop the "payload" that they provide into the infoArray. Now when we want to add a new "item" we don't have to edit dozens of business object to add a new mapping, we can just add it to the infoArrray (keyed by service name) and whoever needs it can get it from that array.

so my entity looks like

```
/**
  * @var integer $id
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
  * @Type("integer")
  * @SerGroups({"modulerevision", "module_revision"})
  */
  protected $id;
  .
  .
  .
  public $servicesArray;
```

In the event listener I end up calling the following method

```
 public function getFiles(ConsumerInterface $entity, $fullPath = false){
        $query = $this->em->createQuery(
            'SELECT f
             FROM FileManagerBundle:File f
             JOIN  f.owners o
             WHERE o.id = ?1');
        $query->setParameter(1, $entity->getOwner());
        $files = $query->getResult();
        return $files;      
    }
```

This works great. The query is executed and I get my array of files and I push it onto $infoArray in my entity.

After running the postLoad event code, we jump back in to Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator at line 480

```
 if ($this->_rsm->isMixed) {
```

At this point the private varialble _rsm is no longer set and the house comes crashing down with the following exception

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/symfony/xesapps/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ObjectHydrator.php line 480
```

Is it possible that calling the additional query during the postLoad event is killing the ResultSetManager being used to hydrate the object being loaded? If so, is there any way around this? Do I need to approach this in a different way?

PS - this works great in another controller where the only object being hydrated is the parent object. It fails in a controller where the object is being hydrated as part of an object graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to access an association in the postLoad event.

From the [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events):

> Note that the postLoad event occurs for an entity before any
>   associations have been initialized. Therefore it is not safe to access
>   associations in a postLoad callback or event handler.

Comment: That makes sense. I see now that I was accessing an association, even thought it was through an interface. Why would it work in one circumstance and not the other? Just the way the dql is parsed and where the entity is in the object graph?

Comment: actually i didn't dive too deep into the internals on this topic but i remembered that some similar issue made me go nuts in the past :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a note for anyone who finds this question in the future. There is a workaround. It isn't pretty, but it seems to work. You can read more at http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1010

That ticket also points to committed code in doctrine two work around this issue - https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/commit/8d13601e39d0fdefdd1d2c0a85704c440b8bdd37, so hopefully a better solution will be coming soon.